# How to filter nested data

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse, plyr

How can I filter a nested dataset (make sure the nest is the exact same as some reference vector or tibble)?

```
library(tidyverse)

rev_vec <-  c("apple", "pear", "banana")

df <- tibble(
  ID= rep(1:3, each =3),
  fruits =  c("apple", "pear", "banana", 
              "Pineapple", "Pineapple", "orange",
              "lime", "pear", NA))

df_vec <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(fruits  = list(unique(fruits)))

## This does not work
df_vec %>% 
  filter(fruits == rev_vec)

## This does not work
df_vec %>% 
  filter(unlist(fruits) == rev_vec)

## This does not work
df_vec %>% 
  filter(all(unlist(fruits[[1]]) ==rev_vec))
```

Basically, I just need to know which ID (in this case 1) matches the reference vector

## expected outcome

Only ID 1 matches the rev vec.

```
df_vec %>%
   filter(....)
```

```r
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     ID fruits   
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <chr [3]>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I added this to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_vec %>% 
    filter(map_lgl(fruits, ~setequal(., rev_vec)))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
     ID fruits   
  <int> <list>   
1     1 <chr [3]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want the output structured, but here is an idea

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = sum(fruits %in% rev_vec) == n())

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID fruits    new  
  <int> <chr>     <lgl>
1     1 apple     TRUE 
2     1 pear      TRUE 
3     1 banana    TRUE 
4     2 Pineapple FALSE
5     2 Pineapple FALSE
6     2 orange    FALSE
7     3 lime      FALSE
8     3 pear      FALSE
9     3 NA        FALSE
```

Another output,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = sum(fruits %in% rev_vec) == n()) %>% 
 filter(new) %>% 
 nest()

# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID data            
  <int> <list>          
1     1 <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it would also match `rev_vec2 <-  c("apple", "pear", "banana", "strawberry")`, which is not a perfect macth

Comment: That is an important detail that you should have included in your question. I dont have time to ammend my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using `identical` to see if the `fruits` for each `ID` are exactly identical to the reference vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(identical(fruits, rev_vec))
```

**Output**

```
     ID fruits
  <int> <chr> 
1     1 apple 
2     1 pear  
3     1 banana
```

Comment: while this indeed works for this example, it does require the data to be in the unnested shape. my data is nested (loaded JSON) and I am looking to for a way to filter the data without unnesting it.